# ArgumentNullException - Get-AzureService

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use the Windows Azure PowerShell module to manage a subscription.

I have downloaded my certificate (the .publishsettings file) and imported it with `Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile` and then I've selected my subscription with `Select-AzureSubscription` neither of which gave errors.

I've also set my subscription using `Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Blah"`

Still, I get a

```
Get-AzureService : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: subscriptionId
```

when running `Get-AzureService`

I've read getting started guides and various documentation but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. Which in my mind, makes this a UX problem that Microsoft should address.

**Update**

I got a bit further, I used

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "Blah" -SubscriptionId 0123
```

which changed the error from `Get-AzureService` to:

```
Get-AzureService : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: managementCertificate
```

But now I cannot set my certificate since the argument wants an X509Certificate type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a better way to authenticate when using the Azure Powershell cmdlets --- `Add-AzureAccount`.  This will prompt you for your login credentials instead of using the service management certificate.

You may still run into some issues because Azure powershell caches your subscriptions in XML files in `%appdata%\Windows Azure Powershell`.

I would recommend:

1. Close the Azure Powershell window
2. Delete the XML files in `%appdata%\Windows Azure Powershell`.
3. Open Azure Powershell and run `Add-AzureAccount`.

This should ensure that you have the correct subscriptions configured.

Comment: Worked like a charm! So easy.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you-

Add-AzureAccount
Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile 
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile *filenamewithpath*

*filenamewithpath* is the publishsetting file with path saved on your pc